# where templates are widgets?

Tags: python, django

please tell me where are the templates for the widget forms.FileInput?

I changed the form as follows:

```
class ChangeAvatarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(
        label='Company Logo',
        required=False,
        error_messages={'invalid':"Image files only", },
        widget=forms.FileInput, 
    )


    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'avatar', 
        )
```

as a result of missing the checkbox that destroys the image and the other functional. I need to know the list of attributes that I can use to change the widget.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking, but you can find information about Django's field widgets in the official documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/